# Search "end with" instead of extension

Tags: php

I found this script that deletes files from a specific extension from a specific folder i would like to know how can i make it to search files that end with instead of extension lets say "-75x60.jpg" please help me out. tx

**File:** file_del.class.php

```
class fileDel
{

     var $extension;

   /** 
   *   @purpose: Sets path and extension
   *   @params : path, file extension to delete
   *   @return none
   */

   function fileDel($extension)
   {
      $this->extension = $extension;    
   }//End of function

   /** 
   *   @purpose: Recursively deleting files
   *   @params : path to execute
   *   @return : none
   */

   function delDirFiles ($path)
   {
      $dir = opendir ($path);

      while ($file = readdir ($dir)) 
      {
         if (($file == ".") or ($file == ".."))
         {
            continue;
         }                

             if (filetype ("$path/$file") == "dir")
             {              
            $this->delDirFiles("$path/$file");
         }                
         //whether file of desired extension is found
                 elseif($this->findExtension($file)==$this->extension)
                 {                    
            if(@unlink ("$path/$file"))
            {
               echo "$path/$file >> <b>Deleted</b><br>";
            }   
         }                   

      } //End of while
      closedir($dir);

   }//End of function

   /** 
   *   @purpose: Finding extension of a file
   *   @params : filename
   *   @return : extension
   */
   function findExtension($file)
   {

      return array_pop(explode(".",$file));

   }//End of function

} //End of class
```

**File:** test.php

```
require_once "file_del.class.php";

$path = "/your/desired/path/to/delete_from";
$ext  = "desired_ext";

$delObj = new fileDel($ext);

$delObj->delDirFiles($path);
```

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/glob :-)

Comment: Just a tip: Don't use that script, looks very fragile and as this is about deleting files, I'd say: handle with care and don't shoot yourself into the foot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
class fileDel {
    var $fileEndsWith;

    function fileDel($fileEndsWith) {
        $this->fileEndsWith = $fileEndsWith;
    }

    function delDirFiles ($path) {
        $dir = opendir ($path);

        while ($file = readdir ($dir)) {
            if (($file == ".") or ($file == "..")) {
                continue;
            }

            if (filetype("$path/$file") == "dir") {
                $this->delDirFiles("$path/$file");
            }
            elseif($this->findFileEndsWith($file)==$this->fileEndsWith) {                    
                if(@unlink ("$path/$file")) {
                    echo "$path/$file >> <b>Deleted</b><br>";
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }

    function findFileEndsWith($file) {
        $length = strlen( $this->fileEndsWith );
        return substr( $file, -$length, $length );
    }
}

require_once "file_del.class.php";

$path = "/your/desired/path/to/delete_from";
$ext  = "desired_file_end_str";

$delObj = new fileDel($ext);

$delObj->delDirFiles($path);
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need a class to do this. Using RecursiveIteratorIterator and RecursiveDirectoryIterator, this is a trivial challenge:

```
<?php
$endswith = '-75x60.jpg';

$directory = './tmp';

$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $directory ) );

$endslength = strlen( $endswith );
foreach( $it as $file ) {
    if( substr( $file, -( $endslength ) ) === $endswith ) {
        echo "Removing $file.\n";
        unlink( $file );
    }
}
```

Anyway, detecting if a string (e.g. a filename) ends with something, you can pass a negative offset into `substr`, so it will return the same number of characters as the string you're testing for. Then, you can check if the two are equal.

Comment: it worked! tx man just what i needed

Answer (score 1):

Another variant making use of the standard PHP recursive directory iterator, combined with a simple `FilterIterator`:

```
<?php

foreach (new FileEndingLister('/path/to/dir', '-75x60.jpg') as $file)
{
    unlink($file);
}
```

The `FileEndingLister` is of some lines of code, instantiating the recursive directory iterator and providing the filter based on the end of each filename:

```
class FileEndingLister extends FilterIterator
{
    private $ending;
    public function __construct($path, $ending) {
        $this->ending = $ending;
        parent::__construct(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)));
    }
    public function accept() {
        return $this->isFile() 
          && substr(parent::current()->getFilename(), -strlen($this->ending)) === $this->ending;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is a great addition in case you need to use that code more than once.

Comment: @BerryLangerak: Yes, or for iterator to array and such.